# what is the standard way to do conversion based on the required type in a template function in c++

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am writing a class that hold several values as string and hold them in an array.

in one function, I need to offer the capability that the user request the value for one item in the list, but since we don't know the type of value, I need ask user how to convert it, so I am thinking of a template function.

sample code is here:

```
class myclass
{
   vector<string> data;
   myClass()
   {
        data=getData(); // data is filled, I don't know the data shape.
   }
   template <typename T>
   T readData(int pos)
   {
      // here I should provide a way so if T is say int, then I convert data[pos] to int and then return back.
      // I am thinking of using is_same<T, int> as follow:
       if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) 
       { 
           return stio(data[pos]);
       }
   }
// is there any better way to do this?
}
```

Apparently this method require a lot of if statement and if the T is not in the list, I can not detect it during compile time.

So I am looking for a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well one key here is that you'll need a `return` if your `if`-condition fails. But as far as a better way? Yeah, I'd say that an [`istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) offers you the most power and dependability. With it you can write your function like:

```
template <typename T>
T readData(const size_t pos) {
    T result{};
    istringstream foo(data[pos]);

    foo >> result;
    return result;
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/EInwBn)

Comment: This doesn't work if the data is a string with several words. for example if the data is " this is a test", this code would not return correct value.

Comment: @mans You can use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of the extraction operator, but you'll need to decide how to handle inputs like: "1 2 3" when an `int` is being extracted. Ultimately you may land with specializing `string readData(const size_t pos)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way because all the code in those `if`s must be compilable.

You are looking for template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
T readData(int pos)
{
  std::cerr << "type not supported" << std::cerr;
  return T{};
}

template<int>
int readData(int pos)
{
  return stio(data[pos]);
}

template<float>
float readData(int pos)
{
  return something_that_returns_float(data[pos]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use boost::lexical_cast<>, where the type that you want to get back is the template parameter.
In your example:

```
template< typename T> T readData( int pos)
{
   return boost::lexical_cast< T>( data[ pos]);
}
```

Be aware that boost::lexical_cast<> throws if the conversion fails (i.e. 'hello world' -> int).

Answer (score 0):

I would use  **std::function**.

The user have possibility to use its own deserialize functions.
Something like the following should works;

```
class myclass
{
   vector<string> data;

   template <class T> //type STRING -> T
   T readData(int pos, std::function<T(std::string&)> converter)
   {

        return converter(data[pos]);

   }

};
```

Comment: What we usually call "deserialize" functions are "extraction operators".